# Disable create collection in spring data mongoDB

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

Can someone tell me how do I configure spring data mongoDB in such a way that it does not create a new collection(if it does not exist) but throws an exception while inserting a document?

Answer (score 0):

Not easy way - [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61841231/with-mongodb-4-is-there-any-feature-to-disable-the-auto-creation-of-collections)

says: turn on access control and then create a role with the appropriate restrictions. Read docs using links there.