# With mongoDB 4, is there any feature to disable the auto creation of collections/dbs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

With **mongoDB 4**, is there any feature to disable the auto creation of collections/dbs? We need to disable the auto creation of collections/dbs in our mongo cluster, so that only defined db and collections should be available in our system

Answer (score 1):

Turn on [access control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and then [create a role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) with the appropriate restrictions.

Comment: What is the appropriate restrictions to disable auto creation of a collection ?

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/. Set your user up in readOnly role and they will not be able to create a collection.

Comment: So... you're saying that disabling a user from creating data will disable their ability to have DBs and collections auto-created... That's like fixing a Windows 10 problem by uninstalling the OS.

Answer (score 0):

**It cannot be done at this time**, per this:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20679

> There is no way to turn off auto-creation of collections and
> databases, but you could use the MongoDB authorization system to
> restrict only certain users/roles to have the ability to do so.

The last part about turning off their authorization, is of course obvious and unhelpful to the question being asked.